# Group MySQL Result by column

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a problem on output the MySQL result to HTML. I had a MySQL result which returns:

```
| title        | category_name | from_where |
---------------------------------------------
| Title num 1  | Journal       | iidl_file  |
---------------------------------------------
| Title num 2  | Books         | iidl_file  |
---------------------------------------------
| Title num 3  | Announcement  | iidl_post  |
---------------------------------------------
| Title num 4  | News          | iidl_post  |
---------------------------------------------
```

How can I preview this data in HTML like this:

```
iidl_file
 - Title num 1 (Journal)
 - Title num 2 (Books)

--------------------------

iid_post
 - Title num 3 (Announcement)
 - Title num 4 (News)
```

Comment: That's a display problem, nothing to do with mysql itself.

Comment: use %2 == 0 to break the data..in mysql use LIMIT ..choice is yours ....give a try bro and do some r&d and provide us the code then :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I would do:

```
SELECT `title`, `category_name`, `etc` FROM `table_name` ORDER BY `from_where`;
```

If you have many records, you will benefit greatly from making sure there is an index on the `from_where` column.

Here is some pseudo-code:

```
$groups = array();
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $from_where = $row['from_where']
    if (! isset($groups[$from_where])) {
        $groups[$from_where] = array();
    }
    $groups[$from_where][] = $row;
}
```

Now your `$groups` will contain arrays keyed by the `from_where` column.

Doing this, you actually don't **have to** even issue the ORDER BY in the query.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea, just use normal mysql result loop with a code like this, not tested but hope it will help

```
$from_all = array();
$from_all[$from_where][] = array('title'=>$title,'category_name'=>$category_name)
```

then

```
foreach($from_all as $from_where=>$array) {
    echo $from_where
    foreach($array as $row) {
        echo $row['title'];
        echo $row['category_name'];
    }
}
```